# Wheeler de Witt for a general Cauchy surface?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-gravity

For the Wheeler de Witt equation space-time is foliated into space-like manifolds. With $g_{0\mu} = \beta_\mu$ and $g_{00} = N^2 - \beta^2$

Then we sort of take this foliation to be a time coordinate and derive the Wheeler-de-Witt equation which turns out no to depend on time.

But in the spirit of the Tomonaga-Schwinger equation where we define the input fields on an arbitrary space-like manifold, if we instead took a different space-like manifold and $\Sigma$ that crossed over many foliations, how would we write such an equation?

I'm guessing it would look something like this:

$$ \left(F[N,\beta] \frac{\delta}{\delta \Sigma(x)} + G^{\mu\nu\tau\sigma}(x)\frac{\delta}{\delta g_{\mu\nu}(x)} \frac{\delta}{\delta g_{\tau\sigma}(x)} + \sqrt{g}R(x) \right)\Psi[g,N,\beta] = 0$$

The first term would have to vanish if the manifold $\Sigma$ matched one of the foliations exactly.

So basically I'm asking if its possible to combine the Wheeler-de-Witt equation with the Tomonaga-Schwinger equation?